WebStorm parameter hints shows "...args: P" instead of parameters
So when I press Ctrl + P it should show me required parameters for specified function. But I see this:

On hover everything is valid:

How to fix this? Can't find any info about this...
Is there some keys combo to show this window like one second screenshot?
